# AEM editContext is null

Tags: adobe, aem

I have created a component and i want to add something in toolbar based on value given in edit dialog

when i came to page editContext is giving proper value

```
// value is a string that i am reading from edit dialog field

if (editContext != null && editContext.getComponent() != null && value != null) {
       editContext.getEditConfig().getToolbar().add(new Toolbar.Label(value)); 
}
```

this code is written in jsp and if condition is true , but when i click on edit and change something in dialog my component got refreshed (not the whole page), now editContext is giving me null .If i refresh the page again it works fine

If i add listener to refresh parent or whole page after edit it works fine but i don't want to do that.

Comment: Have you defined cq:EditConfig for your component?

Comment: yes , i have defined cq:EditConfig for my component